# Read contents of text file and set contents to a variable, based of file extension

Tags: applescript

First off, Im not a Scripter. I am looking for a way to access a specific file,TextFile(via its extension) and read its contents and set those contents to a variable in AppleScript(for simplicity assume TextFile does not need parsing). THE KEY problem to this is that the Specific file is located on an different machine (local server). How Can you access these files; This Script must be able to run on any MAC machine thats connected to network (Windows Machine/Server).

my previous approach was setting a pathVariable to "x.x.x.xx/Share/Apps/CodeBase/test.txt" AppleScript throws errors claiming it "Can’t make file"

Not Sure Why this error appears, since if I change the x.x.x.xx(ip) path to Volumes/share/.... it runs,however I need the IP for reasons addressed earlier in post.

The examples I have seen online and on StackOverflow have not provided adequate results, and I have also not found any Quality tutorials on AppleScripts(so any good resources would be much appreciated).

*EDIT*

For some reason, my ExecuteScript() function is never called, the program just exits. Any explanation would be nice as well

ExecuteScript Function

```
on ExecuteScript()
tell application "Terminal"
// Do Stuff
end tell
end ExecuteScript
```

End ExecuteScript Function

ReadFile Function

```
on readFile(unixPath)

set foo to (open for access (POSIX file unixPath))

set txt to (read foo for (get eof foo))

close access foo

return txt

end readFile
```

End ReadFile Function

Code to Call Functions

```
delay 0.3
try
set diskName to "Share"
-- need logic to check if Volume is already mounted
if diskName is in (do shell script "/bin/ls /Volumes") then

    set contentsOfFile to readFile(filePath)
    ExecuteScript()
else
    -- mount
    mount volume "smb://x.x.xx/Share"
    set contentsOfFile to readFile(filePath)
    ExecuteScript()
end if

end try
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of research and trial and Error, I have found the solution.

Solving the Server Location issue and by proxy solving file error:

```
try
set diskName to "Share"
-- need logic to check if Volume is already mounted
if diskName is in (do shell script "/bin/ls /Volumes") then
    -- Drive is already Mounted,thus can navigate it
    set contentsOfFile to readFile(pathOfFile)
    set isTrue to true   //variable used as a Flag
else
    -- mount Drive 

    mount volume "smb://VolumeToMount/Share"
    set contentsOfFile to readFile(pathOfFile)
    set isTrue to true //variable used as a Flag

end if
end try
```

This solves the first issue by assuring that the server/Volume is mounted on the local machine making it traversable.

Second part was just implementing logic to access that volume path and using the values of the textFile

```
if isTrue then
  if (contentsOfFile is missing value or (length of contentsOfFile) > 1) then
        tell application "Terminal" Run REST OF CODE
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the server a Mac? If so you can turn on "Remote Apple Events" in the Sharing preference pane. Then you can send applescript commands directly to that machine and the task would be easy.

If it's not a mac then your next best bet would be to mount the file server locally first, and then read the file from the mounted disk. All that can be done in applescript with a little effort.

A third approach would be to use unix tools such as rsync or scp to copy the file from the server to the local computer and then read it into applescript. With this approach you'll want to setup SSH keys on each machine so you can run the commands from applescript without the need to supply a password. Without the SSH keys you'll have to issue commands in the Terminal.

So without more information about the server it's difficult to suggest the best solution.

Regarding your error I don't understand it because the following does not error for me. You must be doing something else that's causing the error.

```
set pathVariable to "x.x.x.xx/Share/Apps/CodeBase/test.txt"
```